# After Build Docker mysql Database throw OperationalError

Tags: mysql, django, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I was trying to run a Django project with Docker + Nginx + MySQL, by following this [Link](https://github.com/yoshitakameguro/docker-django-uwsgi-nginx-mysql)  After successfull build, by running

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Here is my **setting.py** Database connection

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'smartCut',
        'USER': 'antu',
        'PASSWORD': 'secure',
        'HOST': 'mysql',
        'PORT': 3306,
    }
}
```

If I use *HOST: 'mysql'*

```
(1045, "Access denied for user 'antu'@'172.25.0.3' (using password: YES)")
```

Error 
But If I use 
If I use *HOST: 'localhost'*

```
(2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

Also, this project cannot find the static file in the admin panel.

Whats I'm doing wrong?

**Update:**

> $ docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                               NAMES
07a5a13e15a1        projectone_web      "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   16 seconds ago      Up 8 seconds              0.0.0.0:8888->80/tcp                web
2431afe3eed2        projectone_python   "uwsgi --ini /uwsgi.…"   21 seconds ago      Up 17 seconds                                                 python
83572753b4ae        projectone_mysql    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   56 seconds ago      Up 52 seconds (healthy)   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build: ./docker/nginx
    ports:
      - 8888:80
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /etc/nginx
    links:
      - python
  python:
    container_name: python
    build: ./docker/python
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
  mysql:
    build: docker/mysql
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secure
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=smartCut
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"

volumes:
  data-volume:
```

> $ docker logs 83572753b4ae

```
2019-07-21T10:00:06.327977Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2019-07-21T10:00:06.328151Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) starting as process 1
2019-07-21T10:00:06.332333Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013242] [Server] --character-set-server: 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous.
2019-07-21T10:00:12.001312Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-07-21T10:00:12.150341Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2019-07-21T10:00:12.290955Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.16'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2019-07-21T10:00:12.817464Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

Comment: This works for me, I can connect to MySQL with this docker compose. Have you changed anything in the code from this repo?

Comment: I try to run two projects with I run one project in 3306 MySQL port and other is 3301 port but both are not working

Comment: have you changed `app/config/settings.py` file and the database configuration? Show this file.

Comment: You need to include the actual error message you're getting as text in the question; don't paste a screen shot of a browser window.  Showing the code or configuration where you're telling the application how to connect to the database would be helpful too.

Comment: `USER` should be `root` in your database settings. And also leave `mysql` as host.

Comment: Thanks, its works but what If I want to use a difrent user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as explained you should use `mysql` as host and `root` as `USER` in your database config :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'smartCut',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'secure',
        'HOST': 'mysql',
        'PORT': 3306,
    }
}
```

`mysql` will be resolved to mysql container IP because container from compose will be connected to the same network.

Also you have set up `root` password for your `mysql` container by using environment variable - `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secure` so `root` have to be used as user.

If you want to create new user you could use `MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD` environment variables - reference can be found in [mysql docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql). Modify your docker-compose accordingly :

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build: ./docker/nginx
    ports:
      - 8888:80
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /etc/nginx
    links:
      - python
  python:
    container_name: python
    build: ./docker/python
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
  mysql:
    build: docker/mysql
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secure #root password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=smartCut #this database will be created for MYSQL_USER
      - MYSQL_USER=antu 
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secure #your user password
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"

volumes:
  data-volume:
```